# Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 20 declared

Tags: android, wear-os

I am getting the following error:

```
 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':Application:processReleaseManifest'.
 > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 20 declared in library com.google.android.support:wearable:1.0.0
```

Here is my Application Build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.ysk.notes"
minSdkVersion 9
targetSdkVersion 20
versionCode 3
versionName "1.02"
}
buildTypes {
release {
    runProguard true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
  }
 }

dependencies
  {
         compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile project(':FacebookSDK')
        compile files('libs/activation.jar')
        compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
        compile files('libs/mail.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
        wearApp project(':Wearable')

}
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong? I had a similar issue for support-v4:+ I changed to v4:20.+ - Now that error went off and I am getting the above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **wear module** must have

```
minSdkVersion 20
```

It is the **wear module** and the  'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.0.0' requires minSdk=20
Then change you build script.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ysk.notes"
    minSdkVersion 20
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.02"
}
```

**The mobile module doesn't require the 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.0.0' dependency.**

About support-v4:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
```

They are different.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'  -> last version in your sdk, in this moment it can be 21.
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+' -> last version with maior release 20 (then 20.xx )
```

Comment: Wear module has minsdk 20 and targetsdk 20. The script i have shown is for the Mobile.

Comment: The mobile module doesn't require the 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.0.0' dependency.

Comment: Great. This worked. Can you help with this strange problem I have: http://goo.gl/ZAIoAP